# MUI Grid placement issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

On MUI grid, after adding only one element the card should apper in the middle. After that, it should follow the given grid system. Is is possible to do it in MUI ? The issue with my grid is that when i add a single element, it appears to be in the left most corner. Here is my code .

```
import React from 'react'
import CropDetailsQuery from '../../api/models/cropDetailsQuery'
import SearchCrops from './components/SearchCrops';
import SearchCard from './components/SearchCard';
import { CropContext } from '../../context/crops';
import { Grid } from '@mui/material';


function Search() {
    const [query, setQuery] = React.useState(new CropDetailsQuery());
    const { crops } = React.useContext(CropContext);
    let cropList = [];
    for (const [name, data] of crops) {
        cropList.push(data);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <SearchCrops setQuery={setQuery} />
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                {cropList.map((crop) => (
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} >
                        <SearchCard key={crop.data.name} query={query} crop={crop} />
                    </Grid>
                ))}
            </Grid>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Search
```

Answer (score 0):

You may modify the `Grid` container like this:

```
<Grid container spacing={2} direction="row" justifyContent="center">
  /*...*/
</Grid>
```

Hope it helps.

Reference from [MUI documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#interactive).